# Trick to call a function inside tenary expression and use its return-value without calling it again

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a neat way to do this:

```
return func(arr) >= 0 ? func(arr) : arr.length;
```

Calling `func(arr)` does not modify anything, so the above works fine.

But I would still like to avoid executing `func(arr)` twice.

Is there a neat way to achieve that in JavaScript?

Comment: `func(arr) || arr.length`…

Comment: what other values does `func(arr)` return?

Comment: @deceze: That would return `true` or `false`, most certainly not `arr.length` (let alone the fact that when `func(arr)` returns -1, it will return -1 instead of `arr.length`).

Comment: Well, you are wrong in assuming that `||` returns a boolean. True about the `-1` though, you'd need to clarify @Nina's request there.

Comment: @deceze: Clarify that -1 < 0? I assumed that the fact that I was using `>= 0` and not `!= 0` would make that pretty obvious.

Comment: Fine, then something like `(i => i >= 0 ? i : arr.length)(func(arr))` is about as good as it gets. See the duplicate for further options.

Comment: @deceze: Yes, thought about it, but wasn't sure it would work. Anyway, this suggestion appears in one of the answers to one of the two questions suggested as duplicate of mine. Thanks!!!

Comment: Frankly though, before writing that sort of abomination, I'd do a simple `const foo = func(arr); if (foo >= 0) return foo; return arr.length;`…

Comment: If `func` always returns `-1` or an integer greater than or equal to zero, you can use this:  `return ~(~func(arr)||~arr.length);`. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5vf3L78m/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let retVal = func(arr);
return retVal  >= 0 ? retVal : arr.length;
```